# bundlerを使用する際のローカルインストールとグローバルインストールの依存関係について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

bundlerを使ってgemをローカルインストールする場合、グローバルインストールされているgemとの依存関係はどうなるのでしょうか？ 
同じgemだったらローカルの方のバージョンが優先され、ローカルにインストールされていないgemだったらグローバルのgemが反映されるのでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/15531

Answer (score 2):

> bundlerを使ってgemをローカルインストールする場合、グローバルインストールされているgemとの依存関係はどうなるのでしょうか？

たとえば、 `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` などでローカルにGemをインストールすると必要なGemは全て `vendor/bundle` 以下にインストールされるためグローバルにインストールされたGemとは干渉しません。

蛇足ですが、 `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` のように `--path` をつける方が好ましいです。（以下でも説明しています）

[bundle install sudoつけない方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34310/bundle-install-sudo%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/34314#34314)