# bundle install sudoつけない方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

現在rails の新規のプロジェクトに対して、bundle installが通らず、何故かsudoをつけると確実に動作するような状況です。
sudoをつけないと

> There was an error while trying to write to
>   /Users/name/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions`.
>   It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.

に出てしまいます。
ネット上で参考になるものが見つけられなく、困っています。
どうすれば、sudo無しで、対応できるか教えていただきたいです。

＊権限問題かと思って当初権限を見たのですが

> drwxr-xr-x  23 name  name  782  4 27 12:22 project_name

上記のように問題がないようでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There was an error while trying to write to
>   /Users/name/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions`.
>   It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.

`/Users/name/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions` に書き込みをしようとしたところエラーが起きたので、書き込み権限の付与が必要です、という内容です。
エラーメッセージの通り、 `/Users/name/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions` の権限を確認して、 権限変更すれば良さそうです。

`sudo chown user_name /Users/name/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions`

蛇足ですが、 基本的に `bundle install` は `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` のように `--path` オプションをつける方が好ましいです。
`bundle install` すると、システムが管理する場所にgemがインストールされるのに対して、 `--path` オプションをつけると任意のディレクトリにgemをインストールすることができるため、複数のプロジェクトをローカルで管理する場合にgemの依存関係を明確にしておけるというメリットがあります。

Comment: 確認したところ、```-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  11897322  4 27 16:58 versions``` で書き込み権限を持っていませんでした。上で記した書き込み権限の箇所のことかとずっと思っていたのですが、教えて頂きありがとうございます。bundle install --path=vendor/bundleも最近ちゅういを受けたばかりだったので、以後入力するようにしたいと思います。ありがとうございました。